# In my code I have the up and down arrow keys working, but for some reason left and right dont seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, arrow-keys

Im making a game for my class and I have everything working, but for some reason the left and right arrow keys dont work but up and down work correctly.
I have everything in Github - https://github.com/Crouton18/game.git

This is the html and java script for the arrow functions

```
    function leftArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("cat");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 20 + 'px';
        }
        function rightArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("cat");
            element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 20 + 'px';
        }
        function upArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("cat");
            element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 20 + 'px';
        }
        function downArrowPressed() {
            var element = document.getElementById("cat");
            element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 20 + 'px';
        }

    function movetheguy(event){
       switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    leftArrowPressed();
                break;
                case 39:
                    rightArrowPressed();
                break;
                case 38:
                    upArrowPressed();
                break;
                case 40:
                    downArrowPressed();
                break;
                }

    <body onLoad="bg(large0.gif);" onKeyDown="" 
          onkeyup="movetheguy(event);" bgcolor="black">
```

Comment: set `position: absolute` for #cat element

Comment: I don't know whats wrong, but your choice of camel casing for onKeyDown then all lowercase for onkeyup should probably be changed. (It bothers me)

Comment: @WoLfulus i have that in a different part of my html  <img src="cat.gif" width="75" height="150" id="cat" style="position:absolute; right:250; top:500">

Comment: @Nexevis will fix

Answer (score 1):

I checked your HTML in github and found that you only have `right` style in your "cat" image. in JS `element.style.left` will not return value if you don't have `left` rule in your `style` attribute.

To fix this, you should either change your JS code to get `element.style.right` instead of `element.style.left` OR change the style in your "cat" image to use `left` instead of `right`

Comment: i changed element.style.right for the func right and element.style.left for the left func the left work perfectly now but when going right it jumps back to the absolute position i believe and doesnt go any further.

Comment: @TylerChretien you did it wrong way. you should use either `element.style.right` or `element.style.left` in your JS code but not both. if you decide to use `element.style.right` in your JS code then you should use `right` rule in your `style` attribute, and the same if you decide to use `left`.

Comment: @TylerChretien you are welcome. You can flag answer as accepted.